# Opening a dialog box from overlay window

Tags: jquery, overlay

I want to open an easyui dialog box through onclick event of a button in an overlay window.
  What happens is, my dialog box opens behind the overlay window.Is there any way to sort out this problem.

Comment: Make sure that you set the CSS z-index properly for each item that is open.

Comment: Like Jay said, z-index is most probably definitely your issue here. If you aren't sure what z-index is, search it on our trusty google.com. In short it adjusts the 'levels' of each element. So if your overlay had a z-index of 1000, then make the dialog z-index: 1001, in your css file.

Comment: sorry guys,now there are too many changes in my app. Dont know why now I am not able to change the z-index of dialog.

Comment: can anyone please tell me the  proper way to change the zIndex of dialog box. I tried $('#test').dialog({zIndex:1001}) and data-options='zIndex:1001'.Both didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing `zlndex:9000` to `zlndex:1000` in the source code.